# How are sockets sending data through packets in erlang?

Tags: sockets, erlang

So I'm reading trying to find more about sockets and I found that the documentation kind of repeats itself without going in any further detail in regards to the way sockets send data:

So what does the `{packet, N}` do when specifying this in the options (when opening a socket) ? Does it include a header of N bytes before the data or does it break the message into N packets? Or does it include a header of N to all the packets that the message ends up being broken into?

I was reading Joe Armstrong's Software for a concurrent world and I found this paragraph:

> The word packet refers to the length of an application request or response message, not to the physical packet seen on the wire.

I can't get my head round the meaning of this. What is meant by the `packet seen on the wire`.

I tried to look into the documentation and I found little referring to what the option does. The brief explanation that I found is that it prepends the message with a N header however I also found this comment in a code written as an example:

```
           %% Usually, it's a good idea to give up in case of a 
           %% send timeout, as you never know how much actually 
           %% reached the server, maybe only a packet header?!
```

According to this, then, the message gets broken into pieces (a random number I presume?) and each gets sent with a N byte header.

My question is how does the `{header, N}` option affect the way data is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excerpt from Joe's book you quote refers to the fact that applications are typically blissfully unaware of how networks arrange data for transmission. Depending on the network type, configuration, and protocols in use, the blocks of data sent over it will vary in size and will be framed with different metadata. Applications typically don't see raw packets, framing information, or the fact that sometimes raw packets are retransmitted due to problems that cause them to be dropped or corrupted.

Your question mentions two options: `{packet, N}` and `{header, N}`. These are quite different from each other.

- The `{packet, N}` option allows `N` to be 1, 2, or 4. It attaches a header of `N` bytes to the front the message. The header specifies, in network order, the length of the message, i.e. the number of bytes in the message.

  If you send a message consisting of `X` bytes, Erlang will prepend to the data `N` bytes containing the network order value of `X`, and send the whole thing. Assuming the receiver has also been configured with the same `{packet, N}` option, it will read the `N`-byte header to determine how many bytes to expect, wait to receive that many bytes, and then deliver those bytes, without the length header, to the receiving application. How the underlying networking software and hardware breaks the data into chunks for transmission across the network is a separate matter hidden from your application.
- The `{header, Size}` option delivers the message to the receiver as a list of `Size` bytes followed by the remainder of the data as a binary. This option makes sense only when the `binary` option is in effect for the socket.

Comment: So then, specifying `{packet, 4}` simply adds a header to the entire message of X bytes (not to the small arbitrary number of packets that the message gets broken into) specifying its size?

Comment: `{packet, 4}` adds a 4-byte big-endian (i.e., network order) integer holding the value `X` to the front of the data. This entire message is then sent. Erlang adds no size headers to any arbitrary chunks that the underlying network might create to transmit the message.